# Arduino UNO + ESP8266 shield returns gibberish

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I tried to get this ESP shield working with my Arduino Uno, but with no success yet. I have connected the shield's TX with the Arduino's digital pin 2 and the RX with pin 3 and configured them in my sketch.

```cpp
SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600);
}
```

If I send an AT command, nothing returns. I got it to return something pressing the reset button on the ESP, but it returned gibberish:

```
)R⸮⸮К⸮Ҹ⸮⸮⸮⸮ښ⸮⸮⸮N֕⸮2%C⸮\⸮×⸮⸮rz⸮⸮⸮H⸮
```

I am making use of the shield seen at this [blog](https://claus.bloggt.es/2017/01/14/using-esp8266-shield-esp-12e-elecshop-ml-by-wangtongze-with-an-arduino-uno/). I would really like to get this working. What can I try more?

Comment: What AT command are you sending?

Comment: basicly just AT, It should return OK or something like that, but it returned nothing. After changing the boudrate of both Serials to 115200. It starts to return Error like described below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The baud rate is wrong.
Use `esp8266.begin(115200);`

You can also set the baud rate of the ESP to 9600 before using it as described in the article you linked.

Comment: I got something to return now, but it is not good. http://prntscr.com/ggual8. I tried to send the commands AT and AT+GMR\r\n to try if it's because of the line endings

Comment: If I now press the reset button on the ESP I get this weird message: co⸮⸮o쏟⸮⸮p⸮>⸮o⸮l`⸮ool`os⸮⸮⸮s⸮sl8⸮o⸮⸮⸮s⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮sp⸮⸮⸮llǏp⸮>⸮o⸮l⸮⸮l`⸮⸮o⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮l`⸮s⸮⸮⸮co⸮⸮ol⸮s⸮c⸮>⸮o⸮l`⸮ool`o9⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮|sls⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮>slsl⸮⸮'⸮⸮8⸮o⸮⸮⸮csooo⸮&⸮cssl⸮&⸮l⸮&⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮lllsd⸮&⸮⸮lllo⸮⸮⸮c⸮ll⸮l⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮pso⸮⸮쓜⸮⸮ll⸮cllpc⸮⸮cs⸮⸮ocscs⸮⸮occll⸮⸮s⸮⸮|⸮⸮ol⸮|cll`sldon't use rtc mem d`ta
sl⸮⸮o⸮
Ai-Thinker Technology Co. Ltd.

qf⸮d^d

Comment: I also found out if I send a command, it prefills AT. So if I just do +RST, it actually will execute a reset. but the other commands still return the busy error

Comment: I have got it working now. I had some other things in my void loop() that blocked the ESP. The solution to my problem was indeed the boudrate.